# Submit webview to appstore

Tags: webview, appstore-approval

I have submitted a web-view for my website to the app-store, and i got a response from them but i didn't understand exactly what they mean by this two lines:

```
Please revise your app to implement all of the following precautions:

- Require that users agree to terms (EULA) and these terms must make it clear that there is no tolerance for objectionable content or abusive users.
- A method for filtering objectionable content.
```

Anyone please can explain it in another word for me?

Comment: You need to have one of those annoying disclaimers that everyone just clicks "Agree" on which contains the information outlined in their response as well as an automatic way to  ensure that if a user of your app violates your EULA that the app will not allow the behavior to be sent out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you need to make a Terms and Agreements page, stating that you don't tolerate abusive behaviour etc. and that you have filtered words and consider some as bad-word or not approriate/not acceptable and thus their account should be terminated if non-compliant.

Comment: Thank you very much, for the down vote no problem people like to do that thanks again :)